# How to recover Minimum Access Profile?

Tags: metadata-api, profile, metadata

The Minimum Access Profile has been accidentally deleted from our organization. How can we recover it (development tools are possible!).

Comment: 'Minimum Access - Salesforce' is a standard profile. I don't think it can be deleted. Maybe it is renamed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete Standard Profiles. Make sure you're logged in to the correct org and/or that the List View you're using doesn't have any filters that would exclude this profile.

Comment: That's interesting. We don't have this profile anymore. Is there a rename history?

Comment: @Julian Not for system automated renames, I'd imagine. But it's brand new, [Summer 20](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_general_new_profile.htm&type=5&release=226), so it should be around there somewhere. Oddly, I can't seem to find it in my Dev Org, either. I'm going to have to do more research on it.